# How can i align content to all four corners of a div (top right, top left, bottom right, bottom left) and have margin on each?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have a div and i want to put an image at the bottom right of the div and some images to the bottom left.  They are different heights so i want to make sure they both align to the bottom of the div.

At first, i made the bottom right align by using:

```
   position: absolute:
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
```

but then i couldn't put a margin around it (as it is out of the document flow).  So then, based on some answers below, i tried to create the jsfiddle above to get it to work without any position: absolute.

Here is my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/leora/FYw2D/.

My only issue now is that I want the images on the left hand side to align to the bottom of the div (versus aligning to the top of the right image).  Also in certain cases i don't have any images on the bottom left but i want to have the same vertical spacing (so if i add an image dynamically, it doesn't reset the container height.

```
.images
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

I tried adding vertical-align and a few other properties but couldn't get both to align to bottom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get anywhere here? Did any of the solutions help?

Comment: @Stuart Kershaw - i updated the question based on a few answers and added a jsFiddle to show where i am stuck . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a good way to achieve this with CSS alone.

`position: absolute;` will remove image from text flow.

The only approach I can see is to place your image in the middle of the text and float it right.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCy3s/2/).

But, you will have to find a good spot in the text to place the image in order for it to look good. You can even write a JavaScript script for this.

The other approach is just to add bottom padding to image's container.

And probably it's a good time to revisit page's design and maybe re-design this element.

#### UPDATE:

Considering your updated question, I've edited your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYw2D/5/).

You can use `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;` to position left images wrapper inside of a parent container. This will work fine if your right image is taller that left ones (like in your example).

I've also refactored your Fiddle to fix some other issues. Please see the code.

Comment: Formin II - thanks.  i took your jsFiddle and added in my details and updated the question.  See my latest question which right now is more about lining up images by their bottom (instead of their top)

Comment: @leora I've updated my answer to reflect your changes in the question.

Comment: Is this solution any different from mine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative positioning to achieve the same `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;` placement... but that won't take your `.bottom` element out of the document flow (like `position: absolute;` does). That said, your element needs to be **within** the document flow in order for margin and padding to be respected anyway.

It sounds like you just need to float it right, apply `display: inline;`, and apply your margin and padding. Place your text content above the image in the source order, and then the image should always fall beneath and to the right of the content above (depending on other unknown layout variables, that is).

```
.bottom {
   float: right;
   display: inline;
   padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
   margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

**Updated**

To fix your new challenge, I added `position: relative;` on `.container` and `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` on `.images`:

http://jsfiddle.net/FYw2D/6/

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  What is your suggestion?

Comment: It depends on the rest of your layout and the other elements on the page. You could get really creative with this kind of problem so it's hard to say without knowing more. A jsfiddle would help with the context.

Comment: If your image size is fixed, you can add bottom padding to it's container.

Comment: @Slava - but I don't want to have bottom padding to the whole container (just the bottom right)